# Restrict the attribute value and the value of the element using XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

I have a requirement where I need to restrict the attribute value and its element's value using an XSD. I've been able to restrict the attribute value to one of

```
JSON
SWAGGER
```

so far, but I also need to restrict the element value to one of

```
letter.c
di.js
```

as well.

XML:

```
<response src="XML">
  <resp name="JSON">letter.c</resp>
  <resp name="SWAGGER">di.js</resp>
</response>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
          elementFormDefault="qualified"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="response">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="resp" maxOccurs="14" minOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="respFilter">
                                <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" 
                                              type="Enum" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="src" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="XML"></xs:enumeration>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="Enum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="JSON">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="SWAGGER">
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="respFilter">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="0"></xs:minLength>
            <xs:maxLength value="1064"></xs:maxLength>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Is there a way I can restrict both of them using an XSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use `xs:enum` as you've done for the `resp/@name` attribute.

Replace

```
  <xs:simpleType name="respFilter">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="0"></xs:minLength>
      <xs:maxLength value="1064"></xs:maxLength>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

with

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:maxLength value="1064"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="letter.c"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="di.js"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Side notes:

- Use self-closing tags to improve readability.
- Your `xs:minLength value="0"` against a `xs:string` base was
  superfluous.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to ask, what if I want to match only `di.js`, in place of `letter.c` any value can come or it can come empty as well

Comment: Logically, if I understand you correctly, that would be equivalent to simply having it be an unconstrained `xs:string`.

Comment: So basically it can come as `<response src="XML">
  <resp name="JSON">letter.c</resp>
  <resp name="SWAGGER">di.js</resp>
</response>` --OR-- `<response src="XML">
  <resp name="JSON">le</resp>
  <resp name="SWAGGER">di.js</resp>
</response>` --OR-- `<response src="XML">
  <resp name="JSON"></resp>
  <resp name="SWAGGER">di.js</resp>
</response>` So I need to allow all of these, but if  the value `di.js` get changed, then that needs to be rejected.

Comment: If you wish to express a constraint that introduces a dependency that one value is allowed only when another attribute or element has a certain value, then you can use XSD 1.1 assertions.  Your comment is getting a bit complicated and hard-to-read, however, and I suggest that you ask a new question rather than try to continue this discussion in comments. Thanks.

Comment: I have started a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466984/restrict-the-a-xml-request-attribute-value-and-few-of-the-element-value