# Restrict the a XML request attribute value and few of the element value

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

This post is an extension of the post :[Restrict the attribute value and the value of the element using XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446944/restrict-the-attribute-value-and-the-value-of-the-element-using-xsd)

Now I am able to restrict all the attribute & element value using the XSD. But I'm now looking to restrict only one or two of the element value and not all of them.

XML:

```
<response src="XML">
  <resp name="JSON">letter.c</resp>
  <resp name="SWAGGER">di.js</resp>
  <resp name="BI">bi.j</resp>
</response>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
          elementFormDefault="qualified"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="response">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="resp" maxOccurs="14" minOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="respFilter">
                                <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" 
                                              type="Enum" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="src" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="XML"></xs:enumeration>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="Enum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="JSON">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="SWAGGER">
            </xs:enumeration>
            <xs:enumeration value="BI">
            </xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="respFilter">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="0"></xs:minLength>
            <xs:maxLength value="1064"></xs:maxLength>
            <xs:enumeration value="letter.c"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="di.js"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="bi.j"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

This XSD allows only the above XML request if it has the below value in it:

```
letter.c
di.js
bi.j
```

But what I'm looking to do now is to dynamically allow few element values so that the XSD validates all the below requests.

1.

```
<response src="XML">
  <resp name="JSON">letter.c</resp>
  <resp name="SWAGGER"></resp>
  <resp name="BI">bi.j</resp>
</response>
```

2.

```
<response src="XML">
  <resp name="JSON">letter.c</resp>
  <resp name="SWAGGER">23.x</resp>
  <resp name="BI">bi.j</resp>
</response>
```

3.

```
<response src="XML">
  <resp name="JSON">letter.c</resp>
  <resp name="SWAGGER">di.js</resp>
  <resp name="BI">dj.c</resp>
</response>
```

So basically, attribute JSON will always have letter.c, anything other than letter.c in JSON should be discarded by the XSD. On the other hand attribute SWAGGER & BI can have any or empty value in it.

Comment: Even without fully understanding what you're trying to do, it feels like you'll be needing XSD 1.1 for your sort of validation.  (1) Is that an option?  (2) Your requirements are unclear:  Minimally, explain *anything other than letter.c in JSON should be discarded by the XSD*.   Realize that XSD is for *validation*, it doesn't *discard* anything.

Comment: 1. XSD 1.1 is not an option here. 2. I meant to say that if anything apart from letter.c comes as a value in JSON, it should not be validated by the XSD. Discarded it the wrong word i used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have validation vary per the value of `@name`, you need assertions or conditional type assignment from XSD 1.1.  If you're limited to XSD 1.0, you'll have to test your constraint out-of-band with respect to XSD, or you'll have to redesign your XML to make it less meta:

```
<response src="XML">
  <JSON>letter.c</JSON>
  <SWAGGER>di.js</SWAGGER>
  <BI>bi.j</BI>
</response>
```

This XML could use a fixed value for `JSON` and enumerations for `SWAGGER` and `BI` in XSD 1.0.